# how can celery execute a periodic task immediately？

Tags: python, celery

I want to use celery to execute a periodic task.
According to the documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries, I wrote down the following code:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'test_celery': {
        'task': 'tasks.login.test_timertask',
        'schedule': 60.0,
    }
}
```

but when I run it as follows:

```
celery beat -A tasks.login --loglevel=info
```

the first task is executed after 60s. 
I want to start the task once the worker starts rather than with 60 seconds delay. What should I do?

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.4-archived/configuration.html#task-execution-settings

Answer (score 2):

You can use [crontab schedules](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) for this:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'test_celery': {
        'task': 'tasks.login.test_timertask',
        'schedule': crontab(), # default, executes every minute
    }
}
```

But you must be aware of the following (as the docs state):

> A Crontab like schedule also exists, see the section on [Crontab
>   schedules.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)
>
> Like with cron, the tasks may overlap if the first task doesn’t
>   complete before the next. If that’s a concern you should use a locking
>   strategy to ensure only one instance can run at a time (see for
>   example [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It 's useful!

Comment: Good to know @resolvewang care to accept the answer?